# JWT Authentication with Vue causes Fatal Error: JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vue.js, jwt, nuxt.js

This is a fairly complicated problem that involves ALOT of pieces, so I posted the [full source code](https://github.com/JoshHadik/stack_nuxt_authentication_question) to GitHub for anyone who wants to help.

**The Stack**

Ok, so I'm trying to setup authentication with a Nuxt.js (Vue framework) client-side app and a Rails server-side API. Here's my project stack:

1. Rails API backend
2. Devise & devise-jwt ruby gems for serving JWT.
3. Postgres Database.
4. Nuxt.js front end application.
5. @nuxtjs/axios package for connecting Nuxt app with Rails API.
6. @nuxtjs/auth package to handle client side authentication logic in Nuxt.
7. Nginx proxy to route requests to the proper service (Rails API or Nuxt App)
8. Docker and docker-compose to connect all four services together (Rails, Nginx, Nuxt, Postgres)

Like I said, a lot of parts. And to make matters even worse, I don't really even know which service is causing problems, though I do have an idea. I'll come back to that later though.

**The Problem**

The Vue App works perfectly fine until I attempt to sign in as an existing user. Once I do, something interesting happens.

It appears to work at first, and even redirects to the proper page on sign in. However, as soon as I reload the page or try clicking on any links, the website freezes and the loading bar hangs indefinitely.

After the website tries to load for a bit, I get this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Along with this error, I get a JS Stack Trace, however, the stack trace isn't always the same. Here are the three I've gotten so far...

JS Stacktrace 1:

```
view_1   | <--- JS stacktrace --->
view_1   | 
view_1   | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
view_1   | 
view_1   |     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x26fd9624fb5d]
view_1   | Security context: 0x140a9a59d921 <JSObject>
view_1   |     1: on [0x1c685bd61259] [_stream_readable.js:~825] [pc=0x26fd96bd1601](this=0x27476ca40f19 <Socket map = 0x2513dd2aaca1>,0x1c685bd160d9 <String[5]: close>,0x27476ca41619 <JSBoundFunction (BoundTargetFunction 0x118981190661)>)
view_1   |     2: connectionListenerInternal(aka connectionListenerInternal) [0x118981190561] [_http_server.js:~325] [pc=0x26fd9706ea91](this=...
view_1   | 
view_1   | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

JS Stacktrace 2:

```
view_1   | <--- JS stacktrace --->
view_1   | 
view_1   | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
view_1   | 
view_1   |     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x3595a694fb5d]
view_1   | Security context: 0x016ed8d9d921 <JSObject>
view_1   |     1: parse(aka parse) [0x34dc366765a9] [/app/node_modules/cookie/index.js:~49] [pc=0x3595a77ee3a0](this=0x297ef7d825b1 <undefined>,0x15d707f39c31 <String[265]: auth._token.local=Bearer%20eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NwIjoidXNlciIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNTQ3MDczMjQyLCJleHAiOjE1NDcwNzY4NDIsImp0aSI6ImUwMWRlNjFkLTRkYzItNDRlMi1iZDY1LWQwYmRmZTcwNGNhZS...
view_1   | 
view_1   | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

JS Stacktrace 3:

```
view_1   | <--- JS stacktrace --->
view_1   | 
view_1   | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
view_1   | 
view_1   |     0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x2bda0b2cfb5d]
view_1   | Security context: 0x1e6ec149d921 <JSObject>
view_1   |     1: setContext(aka setContext) [0x3ef9c763dc89] [server-bundle.js:~2584] [pc=0x2bda0bbaa2d1](this=0x0a10aa8025b1 <undefined>,0x28d2a207a4c1 <Object map = 0x10d1f0bf3091>,0x28d2a207a5b1 <Object map = 0x10d1f0bf2cd1>)
view_1   |     2: createApp(aka createApp) [0x27c44ed85199] [server-bundle.js:~1745] [pc=0x2bda0bb9d782](this=0x0a10aa8025b1 <undefined>,0x2bee19762ce9 ...
view_1   | 
view_1   | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

**My Theory**

I think the problem has something to do with how @nuxtjs/axios or @nuxtjs/auth works with an Nginx proxy.

The reason I believe this is because when I use the exact same setup for Vue and Rails, but connect the two together directly via axios without an Nginx proxy in between them, everything works perfectly.

Which means I know for a fact that the backend authentication and JWT logic works and returns a token as expected, and I know the front end works when connected directly with the backend. This leads me to think that, like I said above, the problem stems from how I have setup The Vue App to communicate with the Nginx Proxy.

Even more specifically, I think the problem might have to do with how @nuxtjs/axios or @nuxtjs/auth works with an Nginx proxy when using cookies.

I think this might be the case because the app only hangs when the JWT cookies and session storage is set. If I delete the cookies in the safari browser and refresh the page, The Vue Website works fine again.

Assuming that my theory is right, here is the relevant code:

**Nginx Configuration:**

```
upstream view {
  server view:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://view;
  }

  # FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY
  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://view;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

**Nuxt Auth & Axios Config:**

```
axios: {
  proxy: true,
  prefix: "/api"
},
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/auth/users/sign_in' },
        logout: { url: '/auth/users/sign_out', method: 'delete' },
        user: { url: '/auth/users/current' }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Rails Routes:**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :atoms

  scope '/auth', defaults: {format: :json} do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'}
    devise_scope :user do
      get 'users/current', to: 'sessions#show'
    end
  end
end
```

**Rails SessionController:**

```rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super { @token = current_token }
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def current_token
    request.env['warden-jwt_auth.token'] if current_user
  end
end
```

**Rails Session Views:**

```rb
# app/views/devise/sessions/create.json.jbuilder
json.token @token

# app/views/devise/sessions/show.json.jbuilder
if user_signed_in?
  json.user do
    json.(current_user, :id, :email)
  end
end
```

**Nuxt Login Page (uses Vuetify):**

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex>
      <v-card v-if="$auth.loggedIn">
        <v-alert type="error" :value="error">{{error}}</v-alert>
        <v-card-text>
          Logged in as {{$auth.user.email}}
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn @click="logout">Log out</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
      <v-card v-else>
        <v-alert type="error" :value="error">{{error}}</v-alert>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form>
            <v-text-field v-model="email" label="Email" />
            <v-text-field v-model="password" label="Password" type="password" />
          </v-form>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn @click="login">Log in</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login () {
        this.$auth.login({
          data: {
            user: {
              email: this.email,
              password: this.password
            }
          }
        }).catch(e => {this.error = e + ''})
      },
      logout () {
        this.$auth.logout().catch(e => {this.error = e + ''})
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

**Docker Compose:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./.tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432"
  proxy:
    build: proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5000:80'
  api:
    build: api
    environment:
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
  view:
    build: view
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./view:/app
```

**View The Code**

Since this is a super complex project and has a lot of pieces, I expect it will be pretty hard for anyone to help with just the given code. For that reason, I setup a GitHub repository with all of the code in it's current state. You can view it [here](https://github.com/JoshHadik/stack_nuxt_authentication_question).

To run the repository, simply clone the project

```
$ git clone https://github.com/JoshHadik/stack_nuxt_authentication_question.git
```

Move into the directory

```
$ cd stack_nuxt_authentication_question/
```

And run docker-compose up --build (assuming you have docker and docker-compose on your computer.

```
$ docker-compose up --build
```

Setup database in new terminal tab

```
$ docker-compose run api rails db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

You should then be able to access The Vue app @ localhost:5000. Additionally, the database should contain a user with the following credentials:
email: test@example.com 
password: password

The login route is at localhost:5000/login

*No Proxy*

I mentioned above that the app works when the API and view are connected directly without a proxy in between. to showcase how that works I created an additional branch in the project called no-proxy. If you want to check it out just open a new directory (not the one you previously cloned to) and run

```
$ git clone -b no-proxy https://github.com/JoshHadik/stack_nuxt_authentication_question.git
```

move into the directory

```
$ cd stack_nuxt_authentication_question/
```

then run docker-compose again

```
$ docker-compose up --build
```

and setup the database in a new terminal tab:

```
$ docker-compose run api rails db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

You can view the Nuxt app for the no-proxy branch @ localhost:3000 and the login route @ localhost:3000/login. You should be able to sign in with the same credentials as above.

**Thanks**

Thanks in advance to anyone and everyone who tries to help me out with this!